# MYSQL WHERE-IN Subquery Runs Forever

Tags: mysql, nested

I have a MySQL table. Let's call it Widgets. The Widget table has 3 fields: **id**, **type_id**, and **name**. I want, in one query, to get all the widgets that share a **type_id** with the Widget named 'doodad'. I've written 2 queries:

1. Give me the type_id of the widget with the name 'doodad'.
2. Give me all widgets with that type_id.

This works. Each query, independently achieves its goal.

But when I combine them into a single nested query, it runs forever, infinite loop style. It looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE type_id IN  (
    SELECT type_id FROM widgets WHERE name = 'doodad'
);
```

Can anyone explain this? Is it because I am writing a nested query which is operating on the same table twice?

Little wheel, why spinnest thou?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There is an issue in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190) and `in` where even uncorrelated subqueries are treated as though they were correlated and re-evaluated for each row.

In the explain plan the select type will likely be showing as `dependant subquery` rather than just `subquery` as would be desired.

I suggest trying the approach described [at the end of this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/) of using a derived table to materialize the inner result set.

Or alternatively you could look at the `constify` [procedure here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,128477) to see if it will assist you in getting around this issue.

Comment: The reason I'm using a WHERE-IN subquery is because I previously was using a JOIN, and against the database of 2 million widgets, it took over two minutes to run. As 2 separate queries, the runtime is under a second.

Comment: @Whit - I've found a couple of workarounds you can try to see if you can get the `in` working.

Comment: I can't believe that 6 years after constify was invented, this still isn't part of mysql.  isn't it just an alias for manually creating a temp table and joining on it?

Answer (score 3):

Using a JOIN risks duplicating results - an EXISTS will work similar to an `IN`, without the duplication risk:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM widgets x
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM WIDGETS y
                WHERE y.name = 'doodah'
                  AND y.type_id = x.type_id)
```

Comment: +1 Good point. Would be interesting to know if that performs better for the OP as well.