# Nested SQL query takes too long

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I'm looking for a way to optimize one SQL query that I have. I'm trying to get how many poems with a certain genre.

Query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)  
FROM
    `poems`
WHERE `id` IN (    
                  SELECT `poem_id`
                  FROM `poems_genres`  
                  WHERE `genre_title` = 'derision'
              )
       AND `status` = 'finished';
```

It takes too long (about 6-10 seconds), because it can't use indexes (because of IN() I think?). Is there a way to rewrite this query in different way to get the same result faster?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL [has a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190) with `in` where it repeatedly re-evaluates uncorrelated sub queries as though they were correlated. Does rewriting as a join improve things?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(distinct p.`id`)  
FROM `poems` p
JOIN `poems_genres` pg
ON  p.`id` = pg.`poem_id`  
WHERE pg.`genre_title` = 'derision' AND p.`status` = 'finished';
```

If not then according to [this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/) (see the section *"How to force the inner query to execute first"*) wrapping it up in a derived table might help.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)  
FROM
    `poems`
WHERE `id` IN
(
 select  `poem_id` from ( SELECT `poem_id`
                  FROM `poems_genres`  
                  WHERE `genre_title` = 'derision') x

) AND `status` = 'finished';
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot of new info for me :)

Comment: Rewriting query using JOIN reduced rows examined by a query from 4266806 to 1644. Works as a lightning :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a EXISTS clause and correlate on the id and poem_id fields

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)  
FROM
    `poems` p1
WHERE EXISTS
(
 SELECT `poem_id`
                  FROM `poems_genres`  pg
                  WHERE `genre_title` = 'derision'  and p1.id = pg.poem_id

) AND `status` = 'finished';
```

Difference between this and IN is it will try to use Indexes instead doing full table scan.