# Query optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Is there any way to optimise this query to something quicker?

```
SELECT id FROM business 
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT business_id FROM business_community GROUP BY business_id)
```

Comment: I am not sure if a left join followed by a `NULL` check would be faster, but I think it's worth trying.

Comment: Just for reference, it is a bug in mysql -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM business AS b
LEFT JOIN business_community bc ON bc.business_id = b.id
WHERE bc.business_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using "DISTINCT business_id" rather than a group by..