# Using IN clause vs. multiple SELECTs

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering which of these would be faster (performance-wise) to query (on MySQL 5.x CentOS 5.x if this matters):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=1;
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=2;
.
.
.
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=50;
```

or...

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1,2,...,50);
```

I have around 50 `id`s to query for. I know usually DB connections are expensive, but I've seen the `IN` clause isn't so fast either [sometimes].

Comment: Almost certainly the same: BUT this would be faster SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id BETWEEN  1 AND 50

Comment: Yeah, that probably would, but I don't have my IDs in consecutive order, it was merely an example.

Comment: please don't give unrepresentative examples: otherwise you might get unrepresentative  answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the second option gives you the best performance; one query, one result. You have to start looking for > 100 items before it may become an issue.

See also the accepted answer from here: [MySQL "IN" operator performance on (large?) number of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514697/mysql-in-operator-performance-on-large-amount-of-values)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you should try it and measure response time: `IN` should give you better performances...
Anyway if your ids are sequential you could try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another post where the discuss the performance of using OR vs IN.  [IN vs OR in the SQL WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause)

You suggested using multiple queries, but using OR would also work.

Answer (score 0):

2nd will be faster  because resources are consumed when query gets interpreted and during php  communication with mysql for sending query and waiting for result , if your data is sequential you can also do just

```
   SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id <= 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was researching this after experimenting with 3000+ values in an `IN` clause. It turned out to be multitudes faster than individual `SELECT`s since the column referenced in the `IN` was not keyed. My guess is that in my case it only needed to build a temporary index for that column once instead of 3000 separate times.