# Different performance mysql and mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm migrating and database from mysql to mariadb. the ruby on rails app is doing the following query using cancan so I cannot change the query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT `buildings`.`id`)
    FROM  `buildings`
    INNER JOIN  `structure_subtypes`
        ON `structure_subtypes`.`id` = `buildings`.`structure_subtype_id`
    WHERE  `buildings`.`id` IN (33553, 33554, 33555, 33556, 33557,
                33558, 33559, 33560, 33561, 33562, 33563, 33564, 33565,
                33566, 33567, 33568, 33569, 33570, 33571, 33572, 33573,
                33574, 33575, 33576,+ ,..., 439515, 439521, 439600, 439602,
                439604, 440016, 440017, 440019, 440275, 440315, 440379,
                440403, 440405, 412987, 439889, 439969, 439980, 440216,
                440218, 440341, 440485, 440486, 440488, 440491, 440494,
                440501, 441458, 441498, 441519, 441536, 443387, 443389,
                443464, 433752, 440109, 440110, 440464, 443938, 440513,
                440514, 443391, 443394, 443353, 443364, 443401, 443486,
                175036, 175037
                          )
      AND  `buildings`.`client_id` IN (175, 47 , 162, 152, 170,
                104, 90, 127, 101, 51, 163, 81, 164, 165, 166, 172, 137,
                174, 106, 108, 161, 158, 169, 97, 123, 136, 102, 157,
                167, 135, 105, 171, 180, 120, 119, 118, 121, 110, 59,
                57, 178, 140, 138, 176, 141, 168, 126, 96, 117, 103, 133,
                173, 131, 179, 80, 100, 95, 116, 142, 147, 159, 160, 154,
                115, 153, 156, 91, 125, 144, 150, 93, 155, 149, 151, 146
                          )
      AND  `structure_subtypes`.`structure_type_id` IN (11, 12,
                13, 14, 15
                          )
      AND  (buildings.created_at >= '2016-12-31 23:00:00')
      AND  (buildings.created_at <= '2017-12-31 22:59:59');
```

The problem seems to be so many items in the IN section

[MySQL "IN" operator performance on (large?) number of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514697/mysql-in-operator-performance-on-large-number-of-values)

but the problem is de difference in performance between MYSQL and mariadb

for MYSQL it takes less than 10 seconds

```
 $ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pPASSWORD database

Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.6.35 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [database]> RESET QUERY CACHE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL [database]> Bye

$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pPASSWORD database < select_query.sql

RESULTS

ouput explain:

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  buildings   range   PRIMARY,fk__buildings_client_id,index_buildings_on_workflow_state,fk__buildings_structure_subtype_id,index_buildings_on_workflow_state_and_created_at,index_buildings_on_client_id_and_created_at
                index_buildings_on_workflow_state_and_created_at    258 NULL    1001    Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  structure_subtypes  eq_ref  PRIMARY,index_structure_subtypes_on_structure_type_code,fk__structure_subtypes_structure_type_id    PRIMARY 4   antifraud.buildings.structure_subtype_id    1   Using where; Distinct
```

output describe table

```
MySQL [antifraud]> describe buildings;
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_id                | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| observations             | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at               | datetime      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| updated_at               | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| workflow_state           | varchar(255)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| structure_subtype_id        | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| svs                      | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id                | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| reference                | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| soc_notify               | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| origin                   | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category                 | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_filtering             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| priority                 | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| creator_id               | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| external_id              | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| duration_time            | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reopening_at             | datetime      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| closed_at                | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cbs_detection_id_legacy  | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cbs_callback_legacy      | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| load_percentage          | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| items_in_special_domains | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

..

```
MySQL [antifraud]> show index from buildings;
+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name                                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| buildings |          0 | PRIMARY                                          |            1 | id                | A         |       72567 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | fk__buildings_client_id                          |            1 | client_id         | A         |          82 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_workflow_state                |            1 | workflow_state    | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | fk__buildings_structure_subtype_id                  |            1 | structure_subtype_id | A         |          78 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | fk__buildings_parent_id                          |            1 | parent_id         | A         |        4535 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | fk__buildings_creator_id                         |            1 | creator_id        | A         |         168 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_workflow_state_and_created_at |            1 | workflow_state    | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_workflow_state_and_created_at |            2 | created_at        | A         |       72567 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_created_at                    |            1 | created_at        | A         |       72567 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_reopening_at                  |            1 | reopening_at      | A         |         806 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_client_id_and_created_at      |            1 | client_id         | A         |          80 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_client_id_and_created_at      |            2 | created_at        | A         |       72567 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [antifraud]> Bye
```

for MariaDB it takes 1 minute 10 seconds

```
 $ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pPASSWORD database



Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 4
Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-1~jessie mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [database]> RESET QUERY CACHE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [database]> Bye

$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pPASSWORD database < select_query.sql

ouput explain:

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  buildings   range   PRIMARY,fk__buildings_client_id,index_buildings_on_workflow_state,fk__buildings_structure_subtype_id,index_buildings_on_workflow_state_and_created_at,index_buildings_on_client_id_and_created_at   index_buildings_on_workflow_state_and_created_at    258 NULL    1001    Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  structure_subtypes  eq_ref  PRIMARY,index_structure_subtypes_on_structure_type_code,fk__structure_subtypes_structure_type_id    PRIMARY 4   antifraud.buildings.structure_subtype_id    1   Using where; Distinct
```

..

```
output describe table

MariaDB [antifraud]> describe buildings;
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_id                | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| observations             | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at               | datetime      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| updated_at               | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| workflow_state           | varchar(255)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| structure_subtype_id        | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| svs                      | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id                | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| reference                | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| soc_notify               | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| origin                   | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category                 | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_filtering             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| priority                 | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| creator_id               | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| external_id              | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| duration_time            | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reopening_at             | datetime      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| closed_at                | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cbs_detection_id_legacy  | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cbs_callback_legacy      | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| load_percentage          | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| items_in_special_domains | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [antifraud]> show index from buildings;
+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name                                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| buildings |          0 | PRIMARY                                          |            1 | id                | A         |       71923 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | fk__buildings_client_id                          |            1 | client_id         | A         |          82 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_workflow_state                |            1 | workflow_state    | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | fk__buildings_structure_subtype_id                  |            1 | structure_subtype_id | A         |          80 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | fk__buildings_parent_id                          |            1 | parent_id         | A         |        4495 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | fk__buildings_creator_id                         |            1 | creator_id        | A         |         170 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_workflow_state_and_created_at |            1 | workflow_state    | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_workflow_state_and_created_at |            2 | created_at        | A         |       71923 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_created_at                    |            1 | created_at        | A         |       71923 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_reopening_at                  |            1 | reopening_at      | A         |         826 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_client_id_and_created_at      |            1 | client_id         | A         |          80 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| buildings |          1 | index_buildings_on_client_id_and_created_at      |            2 | created_at        | A         |       71923 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm playing with the variables in show variables but I do not know how to proceed

Comment: Show output from `explain select ...` on MySQL and mariadb, and `show create table tablename` for each table (and any differences in the latter between MySQL and Maria)

Comment: added explain and describe

Comment: Describe doesn't show the index details that `show create table ... \G` does.  Update: I see you did show index, thanks.  Harder to read that, though

Comment: @anquegi - are there any differences in the DESCRIBE and SHOW INDEX outputs?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE structure_subtypes`

Comment: And buildings too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `from buildings use index (primary) inner join ...`

Comment: It works pretty fast on maridb now, ¿I should add a primary index in the id/key column?

Comment: yes that's true but in mysql there is no need to add this and on mariadb it is needed. i cannit change the query

Comment: sorry, I forgot you said that.  I don't know why it is using index_buildings_on_workflow_state_and_created_at instead of the primary key or client_id.  You could try removing that index (but I don't know what other queries it might be there for) or adding a (id,created_at) or (client_id,created_at) index

Comment: I tried to add that indexes but it doesn't have effect

Comment: What engine are you using?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE` !