# Select data on a MySQL database based on an external list

Tags: sql, r

On a membership database, I have all the info regarding all the members. I have a specific list (.csv file) of 1200 members (membership codes) and would like to select all the data regarding these (and only these) members.

I am working on R, with SQL (dbGetQuery). If my list was short I would do a selection in which the membership code must be IN (... list of codes ...), but with such a big list I don't think this is a possibility. I'm not an administrator, so I can only make queries on the database.

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think maybe it's more a MySQL question than an R question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514697/mysql-in-operator-performance-on-large-number-of-values

Comment: You should be able to pass 1200 rows into an `in` clause.