# Mysql picks up wrong index, sorting index instead of filtering index

Tags: mysql

I've some queries my web application makes to the DBMS Mysql 5.7.23.

The table has around 800k records. This is the DDL of the table with actual indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE `contactlens` 
(
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `lastModifiedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colorCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colorDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext,
  `imageUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastPurchase` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastPurchasePrice` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastSell` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastSellPrice` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturerCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `preset` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `purchasePrice` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salesPrice` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `stock` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `thumbUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trial` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `upc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additionMax` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additionMin` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `axisMax` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `axisMin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `baseCurveMax` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `baseCurveMin` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cylinderMax` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `cylinderMin` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `design` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `diameterMax` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diameterMin` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dominant` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `family` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `material` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pack` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `sphereMax` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `sphereMin` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `taxRate_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_sku` (`sku`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_elol05sqtuwi88exc8cdmqul1` (`sid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_upc` (`upc`),
  KEY `idx_design` (`design`),
  KEY `FKq7sw02khmcn1nqil9pcxkgmfa` (`taxRate_id`),
  KEY `idx_manufacturer_line_duration_sph_cyl_add` (`type`,`design`,`line`,`duration`,`sphereMin`,`sphereMax`,`cylinderMin`,`cylinderMax`,`axisMin`,`axisMax`,`additionMin`,`additionMax`,`manufacturer`),
  KEY `idx_sorting` (`manufacturer`,`line`,`duration`,`sphereMin`,`cylinderMin`,`additionMin`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKq7sw02khmcn1nqil9pcxkgmfa` FOREIGN KEY (`taxRate_id`) REFERENCES `taxrate` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2572246 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The web application shows some of these data and permits to the user to filter them acting on each column (like filters in a Google Spreadsheet doc).

The use could filters these columns:

```
manufacturer | line | type | design | duration | pack | baseCurve (mix/max) | Sph (min/max) | Cyl (min/max) | Axis (min/max) | Addition (min/max)
```

All queries have a default order by. The most frequent queries are:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM `ContactLens` contactlen0_
WHERE 1=1 
ORDER BY contactlen0_.`manufacturer` ASC, contactlen0_.`line` ASC, contactlen0_.`duration` ASC , contactlen0_.`sphereMin` ASC, contactlen0_.`cylinderMin` ASC, contactlen0_.`additionMin` ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

As you can see the `idx_sorting` is used as expected. The query tooks around 6ms, it's good.

[image]

**Query 2**

This time I've filters as well as order by.

```
SELECT *
FROM `ContactLens` contactlen0_
WHERE 1=1 
AND contactlen0_.`sphereMin`<=1.25 
AND contactlen0_.`sphereMax`>=1.75 
AND contactlen0_.`additionMin`<=2.25 
AND contactlen0_.`additionMax`>=2.5
AND contactlen0_.`type`='MULTI_FOCAL'
ORDER BY contactlen0_.`manufacturer` ASC, contactlen0_.`line` ASC, contactlen0_.`duration` ASC , contactlen0_.`sphereMin` ASC, contactlen0_.`cylinderMin` ASC, contactlen0_.`additionMin` ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

Explaining this you can see that **idx_sorting** is used, instead I expected it was used the `idx_manufacturer_line_duration_sph_cyl_add` index.
The query takes 4 seconds: it's a LOT! I don't understand:

1. the "wrong index" is used
2. why even with idx_manufacturer_line_duration_sph_cyl_add, the query tooks so long considering that rows cardinality is 20

[image]

This is the optimization trace:

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "join_preparation": {
        "select#": 1,
        "steps": [
          {
            "expanded_query": "/* select#1 */ select `contactlen0_`.`id` AS `id`,`contactlen0_`.`createdBy` AS `createdBy`,`contactlen0_`.`createdDate` AS `createdDate`,`contactlen0_`.`lastModifiedBy` AS `lastModifiedBy`,`contactlen0_`.`lastModifiedDate` AS `lastModifiedDate`,`contactlen0_`.`sid` AS `sid`,`contactlen0_`.`version` AS `version`,`contactlen0_`.`brand` AS `brand`,`contactlen0_`.`category` AS `category`,`contactlen0_`.`colorCode` AS `colorCode`,`contactlen0_`.`colorDescription` AS `colorDescription`,`contactlen0_`.`description` AS `description`,`contactlen0_`.`imageUrl` AS `imageUrl`,`contactlen0_`.`lastPurchase` AS `lastPurchase`,`contactlen0_`.`lastPurchasePrice` AS `lastPurchasePrice`,`contactlen0_`.`lastSell` AS `lastSell`,`contactlen0_`.`lastSellPrice` AS `lastSellPrice`,`contactlen0_`.`line` AS `line`,`contactlen0_`.`manufacturer` AS `manufacturer`,`contactlen0_`.`manufacturerCode` AS `manufacturerCode`,`contactlen0_`.`name` AS `name`,`contactlen0_`.`preset` AS `preset`,`contactlen0_`.`purchasePrice` AS `purchasePrice`,`contactlen0_`.`salesPrice` AS `salesPrice`,`contactlen0_`.`sku` AS `sku`,`contactlen0_`.`stock` AS `stock`,`contactlen0_`.`thumbUrl` AS `thumbUrl`,`contactlen0_`.`trial` AS `trial`,`contactlen0_`.`upc` AS `upc`,`contactlen0_`.`additionMax` AS `additionMax`,`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` AS `additionMin`,`contactlen0_`.`axisMax` AS `axisMax`,`contactlen0_`.`axisMin` AS `axisMin`,`contactlen0_`.`baseCurveMax` AS `baseCurveMax`,`contactlen0_`.`baseCurveMin` AS `baseCurveMin`,`contactlen0_`.`cylinderMax` AS `cylinderMax`,`contactlen0_`.`cylinderMin` AS `cylinderMin`,`contactlen0_`.`design` AS `design`,`contactlen0_`.`diameterMax` AS `diameterMax`,`contactlen0_`.`diameterMin` AS `diameterMin`,`contactlen0_`.`dominant` AS `dominant`,`contactlen0_`.`duration` AS `duration`,`contactlen0_`.`family` AS `family`,`contactlen0_`.`material` AS `material`,`contactlen0_`.`pack` AS `pack`,`contactlen0_`.`source` AS `source`,`contactlen0_`.`sphereMax` AS `sphereMax`,`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin` AS `sphereMin`,`contactlen0_`.`type` AS `type`,`contactlen0_`.`taxRate_id` AS `taxRate_id` from `contactlens` `contactlen0_` where ((1 = 1) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin` <= 1.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMax` >= 1.75) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` <= 2.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMax` >= 2.5) and (`contactlen0_`.`type` = 'MULTI_FOCAL')) order by `contactlen0_`.`manufacturer`,`contactlen0_`.`line`,`contactlen0_`.`duration`,`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin`,`contactlen0_`.`cylinderMin`,`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` limit 10"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "join_optimization": {
        "select#": 1,
        "steps": [
          {
            "condition_processing": {
              "condition": "WHERE",
              "original_condition": "((1 = 1) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin` <= 1.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMax` >= 1.75) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` <= 2.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMax` >= 2.5) and (`contactlen0_`.`type` = 'MULTI_FOCAL'))",
              "steps": [
                {
                  "transformation": "equality_propagation",
                  "resulting_condition": "((1 = 1) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin` <= 1.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMax` >= 1.75) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` <= 2.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMax` >= 2.5) and (`contactlen0_`.`type` = 'MULTI_FOCAL'))"
                },
                {
                  "transformation": "constant_propagation",
                  "resulting_condition": "((1 = 1) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin` <= 1.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMax` >= 1.75) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` <= 2.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMax` >= 2.5) and (`contactlen0_`.`type` = 'MULTI_FOCAL'))"
                },
                {
                  "transformation": "trivial_condition_removal",
                  "resulting_condition": "((`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin` <= 1.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMax` >= 1.75) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` <= 2.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMax` >= 2.5) and (`contactlen0_`.`type` = 'MULTI_FOCAL'))"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "substitute_generated_columns": {
            }
          },
          {
            "table_dependencies": [
              {
                "table": "`contactlens` `contactlen0_`",
                "row_may_be_null": false,
                "map_bit": 0,
                "depends_on_map_bits": [
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "ref_optimizer_key_uses": [
              {
                "table": "`contactlens` `contactlen0_`",
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "'MULTI_FOCAL'",
                "null_rejecting": false
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "rows_estimation": [
              {
                "table": "`contactlens` `contactlen0_`",
                "range_analysis": {
                  "table_scan": {
                    "rows": 728004,
                    "cost": 171586
                  },
                  "potential_range_indexes": [
                    {
                      "index": "PRIMARY",
                      "usable": false,
                      "cause": "not_applicable"
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "idx_sku",
                      "usable": false,
                      "cause": "not_applicable"
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "UK_elol05sqtuwi88exc8cdmqul1",
                      "usable": false,
                      "cause": "not_applicable"
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "idx_upc",
                      "usable": false,
                      "cause": "not_applicable"
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "FKq7sw02khmcn1nqil9pcxkgmfa",
                      "usable": false,
                      "cause": "not_applicable"
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "idx_manufacturer_line_duration_sph_cyl_add",
                      "usable": true,
                      "key_parts": [
                        "type",
                        "design",
                        "line",
                        "duration",
                        "sphereMin",
                        "sphereMax",
                        "cylinderMin",
                        "cylinderMax",
                        "axisMin",
                        "axisMax",
                        "additionMin",
                        "additionMax",
                        "manufacturer",
                        "id"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "idx_sorting",
                      "usable": false,
                      "cause": "not_applicable"
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "idx_design",
                      "usable": false,
                      "cause": "not_applicable"
                    }
                  ],
                  "setup_range_conditions": [
                  ],
                  "group_index_range": {
                    "chosen": false,
                    "cause": "not_group_by_or_distinct"
                  },
                  "analyzing_range_alternatives": {
                    "range_scan_alternatives": [
                      {
                        "index": "idx_manufacturer_line_duration_sph_cyl_add",
                        "ranges": [
                          "MULTI_FOCAL <= type <= MULTI_FOCAL"
                        ],
                        "index_dives_for_eq_ranges": true,
                        "rowid_ordered": false,
                        "using_mrr": false,
                        "index_only": false,
                        "rows": 364002,
                        "cost": 436803,
                        "chosen": false,
                        "cause": "cost"
                      }
                    ],
                    "analyzing_roworder_intersect": {
                      "usable": false,
                      "cause": "too_few_roworder_scans"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "considered_execution_plans": [
              {
                "plan_prefix": [
                ],
                "table": "`contactlens` `contactlen0_`",
                "best_access_path": {
                  "considered_access_paths": [
                    {
                      "access_type": "ref",
                      "index": "idx_manufacturer_line_duration_sph_cyl_add",
                      "rows": 364002,
                      "cost": 145601,
                      "chosen": true
                    },
                    {
                      "rows_to_scan": 728004,
                      "access_type": "scan",
                      "resulting_rows": 4492.1,
                      "cost": 171584,
                      "chosen": false
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "condition_filtering_pct": 1.2341,
                "rows_for_plan": 4492.1,
                "cost_for_plan": 145601,
                "chosen": true
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "attaching_conditions_to_tables": {
              "original_condition": "((`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin` <= 1.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMax` >= 1.75) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` <= 2.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMax` >= 2.5) and (`contactlen0_`.`type` = 'MULTI_FOCAL'))",
              "attached_conditions_computation": [
              ],
              "attached_conditions_summary": [
                {
                  "table": "`contactlens` `contactlen0_`",
                  "attached": "((`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin` <= 1.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMax` >= 1.75) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` <= 2.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMax` >= 2.5))"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "clause_processing": {
              "clause": "ORDER BY",
              "original_clause": "`contactlen0_`.`manufacturer`,`contactlen0_`.`line`,`contactlen0_`.`duration`,`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin`,`contactlen0_`.`cylinderMin`,`contactlen0_`.`additionMin`",
              "items": [
                {
                  "item": "`contactlen0_`.`manufacturer`"
                },
                {
                  "item": "`contactlen0_`.`line`"
                },
                {
                  "item": "`contactlen0_`.`duration`"
                },
                {
                  "item": "`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin`"
                },
                {
                  "item": "`contactlen0_`.`cylinderMin`"
                },
                {
                  "item": "`contactlen0_`.`additionMin`"
                }
              ],
              "resulting_clause_is_simple": true,
              "resulting_clause": "`contactlen0_`.`manufacturer`,`contactlen0_`.`line`,`contactlen0_`.`duration`,`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin`,`contactlen0_`.`cylinderMin`,`contactlen0_`.`additionMin`"
            }
          },
          {
            "added_back_ref_condition": "((`contactlen0_`.`type` <=> 'MULTI_FOCAL') and ((`contactlen0_`.`sphereMin` <= 1.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`sphereMax` >= 1.75) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMin` <= 2.25) and (`contactlen0_`.`additionMax` >= 2.5)))"
          },
          {
            "reconsidering_access_paths_for_index_ordering": {
              "clause": "ORDER BY",
              "index_order_summary": {
                "table": "`contactlens` `contactlen0_`",
                "index_provides_order": true,
                "order_direction": "asc",
                "index": "idx_sorting",
                "plan_changed": true,
                "access_type": "index"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "refine_plan": [
              {
                "table": "`contactlens` `contactlen0_`"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "join_execution": {
        "select#": 1,
        "steps": [
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Forcing the use idx_manufacturer_line_duration_sph_cyl_add index, explaining the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `ContactLens` contactlen0_
USE INDEX (idx_manufacturer_line_duration_sph_cyl_add)
WHERE 1=1 
 AND contactlen0_.`sphereMin`<=1.25 
 AND contactlen0_.`sphereMax`>=1.75 
 AND contactlen0_.`additionMin`<=2.25 
 AND contactlen0_.`additionMax`>=2.5
 AND contactlen0_.`type`='MULTI_FOCAL'
ORDER BY contactlen0_.`manufacturer` ASC, contactlen0_.`line` ASC, contactlen0_.`duration` ASC , contactlen0_.`sphereMin` ASC, contactlen0_.`cylinderMin` ASC, contactlen0_.`additionMin` ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

This is the explanation of the query:

[image]

So the "right" index is used; even if rows cardinality is 403245 (so it's much much bigger than before), the query takes 400ms.

I created indexes based on [this paper](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

What are best indexes I can use for cover most of queries can be generated in my case?

Why in query 2 the "right" index is much faster the "wrong" one even if it works on 400k rows?

How can I hint mysql (without doing that explicitly) to use the right index?

========  COMPARISON WITH MYSQL 8 AND RDS AURORA  ======

As suggested from @oysteing I tested query 2 on Mysql 8 (8.0.11 and 8.0.13) and RDS Aurora. Here results I got

**Mysql 8.0.11**

Optimizer trace: https://codeshare.io/2BXVeK

[image]

**Mysql 8.0.13**

Optimizer trace: https://codeshare.io/5Ookyr

and trying to use histograms on columns:

https://codeshare.io/2KdgO7

[image]

**RDS Aurora**

Optimizer trace: https://codeshare.io/5X4Ngj

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52033986/3481706

In your case, the query optimizer evidently thinks that it can read just a few rows (20) from the idx_sorting index to find the 10 first rows that satisfies the WHERE condition.  This seems a bit strange since EXPLAIN says that it estimates only 0.62% to satisfy the conditions. (Maybe there is a bug in the LIMIT optimization here.  I might be able to tell more if I had the optimizer trace.)  The end result is that by using idx_sorting, it will access far more than the estimated 20 rows before it has found 10 rows that satisfy the query.

You could try upgrading to MySQL 8.0 and see if this problem has been fixed.  With 8.0, you can also create histograms over the columns used to hopefully improve the filtering estimate.

In general, when creating composite indexes, you should put columns that is used in equality conditions first.  It is difficult to create an index that will have good coverage for all types of queries, since MySQL will only be able to use the prefix of the index for which all columns, except the last, have an equality condition.  This is improved in MySQL 8.0 with the new [skip-scan access method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-skip-scan).  This method allows for one gap in the index prefix to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your details reply. I added optimizer trace. I'll give a try with Mysql 8 and Amazon Aurora (I'm curios if there is some optimization there). To complete your answer, could you suggest what indexes you'd use not knowing exactly what combination of filters the user will select? Columns are the one I pointed out in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @drenda Thanks for posting the optimizer trace.  It seems that most rows is of type MULTI_FOCAL.  It also seems that the filtering from the conditions on the min/max columns is not taken into account when estimating how many rows needs to be read if using idx_sorting index.  This may have been fixed in 8.0, but not quite sure.  For the given query, I would think the best index would be an index on type and the min/max column that gives most filtering.   It may also help to include the other used min/max columns in the index to provide for index condition pushdown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did some tests with Mysql8 and Aurora. I'm a bit disappointed about that. I didn't see many changes with my query :-( I added new optimizer traces as sake of completeness.

Comment: @drenda I suggest you file a bug report on bugs.mysql.com for this.