# Mysql Update IN condition

Tags: mysql

I can't succeed to have a "quick" (< 6 minutes)  with a query :
(the select himself take 10 sec max)

```
UPDATE
    peel_utilisateurs AS PU
SET
    PU.online = 3,
    PU.date_desactivation = NOW()
WHERE
    PU.id_utilisateur IN(
    SELECT
        PC.id_utilisateur
    FROM
        peel_commandes AS PC
    GROUP BY
        PC.id_utilisateur
    HAVING
        MAX(PC.o_timestamp) <(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    ORDER BY
        `PC`.`o_timestamp`
    DESC
        )
```

Someone Could help me ? :)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the IN operator with a JOIN. In general, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514697/mysql-in-operator-performance-on-large-number-of-values), the IN operator is slower than a JOIN for large datasets.

```
UPDATE
    peel_utilisateurs AS PU
    INNER JOIN peel_commandes AS PC 
    ON 
        PU.id_utilisateur = PC.id_utilisateur 
        AND PC.o_timestamp <(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

SET
    PU.online = 3,
    PU.date_desactivation = NOW()
```