# Hibernate IN clause throwing error while using more IN data

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-transactions, jpa

Im using below query to fetch the data using hibernate IN clause,

```
select emp from Employee emp where emp.employeeParentCompanyDetails in (:empParentCompDetails)

TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery(fetchQuery,Employee.class);
                query.setParameter("empParentCompDetails", <more than 650 params>);
                List<Employee> employeeDetailss = query.getResultList();
```

and method is annotation with

```
@Transactional(value = "JpaTxn", readOnly = true, timeout = 900)
```

Exception:

> 16:44:30.462 [main] DEBUG
> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl
>
> - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
>
> java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack
> trace     at
> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:143)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.setRollbackOnly(JpaTransactionManager.java:684)

Its working if I pass upto 550 ids in IN clause. So its due to transaction timeout?

Suggest me to fix this scenario.

Comment: Underlying DB may also have limitation for IN([1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit)/[2100 - num of params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45082468/5070879) depending of vendor). Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: its oracle.. but here if go more than 600 itself its throwing this error

Comment: You are getting such a big data from database with any pagination ? That whose design I think. A way is create a temporary table  and do subquery https://stackoverflow.com/a/35309127/4207306