# How to get duplicate values that have same name, number, and city?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ord
     , custname
     , custnumber
     , city 
  FROM ord 
 WHERE custnumber IN ( SELECT custnumber 
                         FROM ord 
                        GROUP 
                           BY custname
                            , custnumber
                            , city 
                       HAVING COUNT(custnumber) > 1 ) 
 ORDER 
    BY custnumber DESC
```

And I got this

> #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: Perhaps try using a JOIN instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL "IN" operator performance on (large?) number of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514697/mysql-in-operator-performance-on-large-number-of-values)

Comment: I tried and I used JOIN " select t1.`CUSTNAME`,t1.`CUSTNUMBER`,t1.`CITY` from ORD t1 join ( select `CUSTNUMBER` from ORD group by `CUSTNAME`, `CUSTNUMBER`, `CITY` having count(*) >= 3 ) t2 on t1.`CUSTNUMBER` = t2.`CUSTNUMBER` ORDER BY `CUSTNUMBER` desc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and  I got a solution.
I used this query "

select t1.`CUSTNAME`,t1.`CUSTNUMBER`,t1.`CITY` from ORD t1 join ( select `CUSTNUMBER` from ORD group by `CUSTNAME`, `CUSTNUMBER`, `CITY` having count(*) >= 3 ) t2 on t1.`CUSTNUMBER` = t2.`CUSTNUMBER` ORDER BY `CUSTNUMBER` desc"

I used Join instead of IN.