# IN function mysql - LIMIT

Tags: mysql

Is there any limit for a no. of value inside `IN` function of `MySQL`, Currently I am building social network and I am trying to fetch all feeds from people who person follow.

But my concern here is, what if a user has 1000 or 10,000 following. Can `IN` function inside `MySQL` take those 10,000 inside `IN` and get the value? Also, will it have speed impact?

E.g, `SELECT * from feeds where ID in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....,1000,...10000)`

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514697/mysql-in-operator-performance-on-large-number-of-values  ---> Check this out sir!

Answer (score 0):

This is [properly documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in):

> The number of values in the `IN()` list is only limited by the [`max_allowed_packet` value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet).

So basically the limit is based on the maximum length of a SQL statement - which defaults to 64 MB. There is little chance that you will ever hit this limit.

However, performance *will* suffer if you use a very large list of values to filter your data. In that case, a better option would be to put the list values in a table (as rows), and then use `exists` for filtering.