# Count & Group By Conflict

Tags: mysql

I'm having a conflict in the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS poststotal FROM posts GROUP BY category
```

The following query returns the poststotal containing the number of categories instead of the total posts count groupped by categories.

So:

```
TABLE: posts(title,category)
----------------------------
foo1  |  art
foo2  |  politic
foo2  |  politic
foo3  |  fun
```

Will return:

```
 4
```

Instead of:

```
3 posts
```

How to deal with that?

Comment: It returns `4`? Is `categories` a different column than `category`?

Comment: Noone can understand what you're asking. Three people so far have given correct answers to how they are interpreting this confusing question. Please clarify what you are asking in terminology that people can understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* get count for each category */
SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS poststotal FROM posts GROUP BY category;
```

your original query should return 3, it could be caused by whitespace stored in column category, try

```
/* verify */
select title, length(category) from posts;

/* ensure whitespace trimmed */
SELECT COUNT(*) AS poststotal FROM posts GROUP BY trim(category);
```

> hmm, thanks, but i want to get the total number of all posts but only one post of each category :) also the categories are fully trimmed

is quite different from what you had described

```
select 
  *
from posts 
group by category

/* the above will return single posts for each category */
```

Comment: hmm, thanks, but i want to get the total number of all posts but only one post of each category :) also the categories are fully trimmed

Comment: Shouldn't his original return something like `[1, 2, 1]` or `[1, 1, 1, 1]` if there is a whitespace in a category which makes them not match? The `GROUP BY category` should still be applied, despite the `category` column not being `SELECT`ed, right?

Comment: @hangy - OP said will return 4 posts

Comment: When i fetch it i only get One category, but the poststotal contains 4 :( which means they are matched successfully

Comment: @David - `"category"!="category "`, the fetch should return two categories instead, which mean you category indeed contains whitespace

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure if I understood your question 100%, but how about that?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM poststotal
WHERE category IN
(
    SELECT category
    FROM poststotal
    GROUP BY category
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
)
```

Comment: i see that you query is so hungry for memory ;)

Comment: @David - `IN` with a subquery [is completely inefficient in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190). Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM poststotal WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM (SELECT category FROM poststotal GROUP BY category HAVING COUNT(*) > 0) as D)` [as discussed here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the count to be grouped by categorys, don't groub by. do it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS poststotal FROM posts
```

(it's *that* easy, i think i missunderstood your question... but i'll give it a try)

Comment: Noo! that missed the whole point, i want to fetch the number of posts under unique categories, there must be a group by, i've successed at it with mysql_num_rows but i prefer to get this done using count for performance issues