# Fetch duplicate rows with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to develope a query to fetch the rows having duplicate values, i need to fetch both records i.e duplicating record and the real one, for example

### table

```
id  keyword
-------------------
1   Apple
2   Orange
3   Apple
4   Grape
5   Banana
6   Grape
```

The query result should be:

```
id  keyword
-------------------
1   Apple
3   Apple
4   Grape
6   Grape
```

Please anyone help me!

Comment: Why not use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
select * from 
table where keyword in
(select keyword 
from table
group by keyword 
having count(keyword)>1)
```

Comment: @Saritha You should try consider it as an answer if it worked.

Comment: @Luv Guess she isn't accepting any answers. See her questions history! :O

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.keyword                                     
FROM table t1              
INNER JOIN table t2                   
ON t1.id != t2.id           
AND t1.keyword=t2.keyword
```

Tested on SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44dbb/1/0

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But i am fetching records from only one table, not two tables, so i think this INNER JOIN is not needed.

Comment: Please check this : [MySQL “IN” queries terribly slow with subquery but fast with explicit values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018284/mysql-in-queries-terribly-slow-with-subquery-but-fast-with-explicit-values)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` t1
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` t2 WHERE t2.keyword = t1.keyword) > 1
```

And another way:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table` t1
JOIN `table` t2 ON t1.keyword = t2.keyword
WHERE t1.id != t2.id
```