# How to form a query across two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am strugling forming a query to accomplish what I need using LEFT JOIN.  I'm afraid that I'm going about this the wrong way, so I reach out to the community.

I have two databases, one for **categories** and one for **items** as follows

```
CATEGORIES
id       name          private
1        Apples        1
2        Oranges       1
3        Grapes        0


ITEMS
id       name          category
1        Mcintosh        1
2        Fuji            1
3        Green           3
```

**The Question**

What I need to do is form a query that will select only the CATEGORIES that are private = 1 and that also have cases assigned to their category id (ie. cannot have 0 cases such as the Oranges category).

So in this case, my query would result in only 1 result:  Apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.* from
categories c,
(select distinct category from items) i 
where c.id = i.category and c.private = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform what you ask with a `LEFT JOIN`. To get rid of the categories that don't have any occurrences in them, you need a `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.name)
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN items i
ON c.id = i.category
WHERE c.private = 1;
```

Here is a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f15f/5

Here you have a very nice explanation of `JOINS` in SQL and why what you need is a `INNER JOIN`: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: "name" - ambiguous, also it will print out "Oranges" in addition to "Apples". Also there's a typo (semicolon) in line #4.

Comment: Everything. Thanks for the typos!

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to use join, the `in` statement will work just fine. As you can see it verifies if the desired value is in a selected list.

```
SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES WHERE private = 1 and id in (select distinct category from items)
```

[See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71f53/1)

Comment: "In" may be very slow. I wouldn't use it in a such a simple query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018284/mysql-in-queries-terribly-slow-with-subquery-but-fast-with-explicit-values

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `INNER JOIN` and `DISTINCT`

```
 SELECT DISTINCT name FROM CATEGORIES 
 INNER JOIN ITEMS ON CATEGORIES.id=ITEMS.category 
 WHERE CATEGORIES.private=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be usfull if you tell us index and table sizes to optimize performance, I think this is the rigth approach

```
SELECT c.Name FROM Categories c 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM items) i 
     ON c.id = i.category 
WHERE c.private = 1
```