# MySQL update takes too long

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

We have more than 20 million records in a table and we tried to update 3K records but it took more than 7 mins and it didn't complete, so terminated the query.

Sample query,

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET STATUS = 'PENDING'
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM TMP_TABLE_A_STATUS_FIX
);   /*took more than 7 mins and didn't complete even after that*/
```

We collected all the ids which needs to be updated in a temp table TMP_TABLE_A_STATUS_FIX(has only 3K records).

As the above query took too long, we updated individually like,

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET STATUS = 'PENDING' WHERE ID = 1;
UPDATE TABLE_A SET STATUS = 'PENDING' WHERE ID = 2;
UPDATE TABLE_A SET STATUS = 'PENDING' WHERE ID = 3;
.
.
.
UPDATE TABLE_A SET STATUS = 'PENDING' WHERE ID = 2999;
UPDATE TABLE_A SET STATUS = 'PENDING' WHERE ID = 3000; /*updated all 3K recordds in 0.00 secs*/
```

I really do not understand what is wrong with the `IN` query.

Can someone explain what is wrong in the update which has `IN`in where clause and why it didn't complete even after 7 mins?

Note - ID in TABLE_A is primary key and its indexed. STATUS in TABLE_A is also indexed. We removed the index for STATUS as we thought updating the index column may take time due to index re-organization but that didn't help.

Comment: Do you have index on ID column? without index tables with large number of records take too much time due to massive IO operatore to filter the effected records.

Comment: @Adil, yes we do have indexes, updated the question.

Comment: My guess is that on each `UPDATE` call, your query checks that the `ID` it is current examining matches an `ID` in the `TMP_TABLE_A_STATUS_FIX` table, which it does by examining every `ID` in the `TMP_TABLE_A_STATUS_FIX` table. Thats 3k * 3mil operations.

Comment: TABLE_A.ID and TMP_TABLE_A_STATUS_FIX.ID both need indexed.

Comment: alter table TMP_TABLE_A_STATUS_FIX add index (id)

Comment: IN is an identified database takes too long to process mostly if we are working a huge data from our database, use other way like exists..

Comment: Similar issue was discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018284/mysql-in-queries-terribly-slow-with-subquery-but-fast-with-explicit-values

Comment: @Tyler - you are right, now I understand the delay.

Comment: @SIDU - indexing temp table didn't fix, forgot to mention in the question. sorry.

Comment: @Rocherlee - thanks for the link, helped me to understand how bad the subqueries are in big data sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insetad of using an in clause try with an inner join

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
INNER JOIN TMP_TABLE_A_STATUS_FIX on TABLE_A.ID = TMP_TABLE_A_STATUS_FIX .ID
SET STATUS = 'PENDING';
```

Comment: Credits should go to @Tyler and #Rocherlee's comments as well.

Comment: @whoami .. i have not see the comment .. but  .. i take look

Comment: @whoami   for credit to #Tyler and #Rocherlee's proper index are always usefull