# Why two mysql selects executed separately are much faster than one combined?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I want to understand the case when I run two queries separately i takes around 400ms in total, but when I combined them using sub-select it takes around 12 seconds.
I have two InnoDB tables:

- event: 99 914 rows
- even_prizes: 24 540 770 rows

Below are my queries:

```
SELECT 
  id
FROM 
  event e
WHERE
  e.status != 'SCHEDULED';
 -- takes 130ms, returns 2406 rows
```

```
SELECT 
 id, count(*) 
FROM 
 event_prizes 
WHERE event_id in (
    -- 2406 ids returned from the previous query
) 
GROUP BY
 id;
-- takes 270ms, returns the same amount of rows
```

From the other side when I run the query from below:

```
SELECT 
 id, count(*) 
FROM 
 event_prizes 
WHERE event_id in (
    SELECT 
      id
    FROM 
      event e
    WHERE
      e.status != 'SCHEDULED'
) 
GROUP BY
 id;
-- takes 12seconds
```

I guess in the second case MySQL makes the full-scan of the event_prizes table ?
Is there any better way to create a single query for this case ?

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE  statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Please check comments in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018284/mysql-in-queries-terribly-slow-with-subquery-but-fast-with-explicit-values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL "IN" queries terribly slow with subquery but fast with explicit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018284/mysql-in-queries-terribly-slow-with-subquery-but-fast-with-explicit-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `INNER JOIN` instead of a sub-select:

```
SELECT ep.id, COUNT(*) 
FROM event_prizes ep INNER JOIN event e ON ep.event_id = e.id 
WHERE e.status <> 'SCHEDULED'
GROUP BY ep.id
```

Make sure you are using

- a `PRIMARY KEY` on `event.id`
- a `PRIMARY KEY` on `event_prizes.id`
- a `FOREIGN KEY` on `event_prizes.event_id`

You can also try the following indices at least:

- `event(status)`

Comment: But as always, the key to this is indexes

Comment: I've tried that and to get the end result it takes around 9 seconds - still It cannot be compare to 400ms ..

Comment: @tomgal - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table so we can dig deeper.