# SQL Performance using JOIN instead of IN CLAUSE

Tags: sql-server, performance, join

I see a lot of places suggesting using INNER JOIN's instead of writing IN CLAUSES because of performance reasons. None of them explain why, though. Can someone provide a detailed explanation why that is?

Comment: that is not actually true, in most cases that i have seen, they perform the same, these type of issues are very data/schema related and it is not like one size fits all thing, so if there is a problem you should check the execution plans and see what is causing a problem.

Comment: This is implementation dependant. Some products optimise correlated sub queries badly and always use nested loops. Others don't. Often they don't have the same semantics anyway unless `DISTINCT` is added to the `JOIN` version.

Comment: Try googling, someone already asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274618/inner-join-and-where-in-clause-performance

Comment: Related, if not exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2577174/102937

Comment: Read this article very informative sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join  and also http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/