# Mysql inner join vs in clause performance

Tags: mysql, performance, join, in-clause

I have a query to get data of friends of user. I have 3 tables, one is user table, second is a user_friend table which has user_id and friend_id (both are foreign key to user table) and 3rd table is feed table which has user_id and feed content. Feed can be shown to friends. I can query in two ways either by join or by using `IN` clause (I can get all the friends' ids by graph database which I am using for networking).

Here are two queries:

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM feed a
INNER JOIN user_friend b ON a.user_id = b.friend_id
WHERE b.user_id = 1;
```

In this query I get friend ids from graph database and will pass to this query:

```
SELECT
 a.*
FROM feed a
WHERE a.user_id IN (2,3,4,5)
```

Which query runs faster and good for performance when I have millions of records?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inner join and where in() clause performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274618/inner-join-and-where-in-clause-performance)

Comment: That question has sub query, i have actual value in IN Clause. I don't need to query a table to get values. But i have avg of 1000 values inside IN Clause.

Comment: They're two different queries. What's better; a hammer or a screwdriver?

Answer (score 1):

With suitable indexes, a one-query `JOIN` (Choice 1) will almost always run faster than a 2-query (Choice 2) algorithm.

To optimize Choice 1, `b` needs this composite index: `INDEX(user_id, friend_id)`.  Also, `a` needs an index (presumably the `PRIMARY KEY`?) starting with `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your desired result when you have a compared big data in your subquery their always a join is much preferred for such conditions. Because subqueries can be slower than **LEFT [OUTER] JOINS / INNER JOIN *[LEft JOIN is faster than INNER JOIN]***, but in my opinion, their strength is slightly higher readability.

So if your data have fewer data to compare then why you chose a complete table join so that depends on how much data you have.

In my opinion, if you have a less number of compared data in **`IN`** than it's good but if you have a subquery or big data then you must go for a **`join`**...

Comment: I have actual value in IN Clause. I don't need to query a table to get values. But i have avg of 1000 values inside IN Clause. I don't have any sub query.

Comment: if this count equal to the number of records in the table then you can go for the `IN` otherwise use `JOIN`