# performance of "where id in(ids)"?

Tags: mysql, performance

is it okay to use the following query? how is the performance?

```
select * from table where id not in ( 2000 or much more ids here)
```

my initial test comes up very fast, but I guess it is because I am the only who is using the server right now.

Comment: As long it's not a correlated subquery I think this should be fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have an index it can be very fast.

However there is a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32665) in MySQL (possibly fixed in MySQL 5.5) where if there is no index, it won't just be slow, it will be *incredibly* slow. This because the subquery can be detected as a `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` (correlated subquery) even when it is not. You can see whether MySQL is using the correct query plan by running `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and checking that `key` is not NULL for your subquery. I have made another post about this bug with some more details:

- [Why would an IN condition be slower than “=” in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190)

You can also consider rewriting your query to use `JOIN` instead of `IN` to avoid this bug.

Comment: // since ID is primary key, i think it would be fine. Thank you for your clear answer once again!