# SQL query not returning unique results. Which type of join do I need to use?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u 
JOIN user_categories uc ON u.user_id = uc.user_id 
WHERE (uc.category_id = 3 OR uc.category_id = 1)
```

It currently returns:

```
Joe,Smith,60657,male
Joe,Smith,60657,male
Mickey,Mouse,60613,female
Petter,Pan,60625,male
Petter,Pan,60625,male
Donald,Duck,60615,male
```

If the user belongs to both categories it currently returns them twice.  How can I return the user only once without using SELECT DISTINCT, regardless of how many categories they belong to?

Comment: Why do you have the restriction "without using SELECT DISTINCT"?

Comment: I like to stay away from SELECT DISTINCT. I consider it bad practice and believe the query is not written correctly if DISTINCT is necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a semi join. This can be achieved with a sub query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * 
       FROM user_categories uc 
       WHERE u.user_id = uc.user_id AND  
       uc.category_id IN(1,3))
```

In MySQL the performance of sub queries is quite problematic however so a `JOIN` and duplicate elimination via `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` may perform better.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about MySQL, but in Postgres you *may* get better performance in the semi-join version from

```
SELECT * FROM user u 
WHERE u.user_id 
IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_categories uc WHERE uc.category_id IN (1,3));
```

I would expect `SELECT DISTINCT` to run fastest but I have learned my expectations and DB performance are often much different!

Comment: In SQL Server `in` and `exists` would both get the same plan and be better than a `JOIN` followed by elimination of duplicates. MySQL has some problems however http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190

Comment: Interesting. I believe PG decides based on an estimated of the selectivity of the subquery WHERE clause, but I generally try a few versions and hit `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a GROUP BY

```
SELECT * FROM user u
JOIN user_categories uc ON u.user_id = uc.user_id
WHERE uc.category_id = 3 OR uc.category_id = 1
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: That won't work with SELECT * since everything else than user_id must be in an aggregate.

Comment: @Andrew - Not in MySQL. Though the `uc` records returned would be arbitrary. See http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: Thanks. Ooops! Very non-standard, although useful.