# logic in HAVING clause to get multiple values of a group by result

Tags: sql, oracle

Imagine I have a table with data as below:

```
ROLE_ID | USER_ID  |  CODE
---------------------------------
 14     | USER A   |   001
 15     | USER A   |   002
 11     | USER B   |   004
 13     | USER D   |   005
 13     | USER A   |   001
 15     | USER B   |   009
 15     | USER D   |   005
 12     | USER C   |   004
 15     | USER C   |   008
 13     | USER D   |   007
 15     | USER D   |   007
```

I want to get the User ids and codes that only have 13 and 15 role_ids. So based on the data above I would like back the following

```
USER D |  005
USER D |  007
```

I have the query below, however, it only brings back one, not both.

```
   SELECT a.user_id, a.code
   FROM my_table a
   WHERE a.ROLE_ID in (13,15,11,14)
   group by a.USER_ID, a.code
    having sum( case when a.role_id in (13,15) then 1 else 0 end) = 2
    and sum( case when a.role_id in (11,14) then 1 else 0 end) = 0  
   ORDER BY USER_ID
```

The above query only brings

```
USER D |  005
```

rather than

```
USER D |  005
USER D |  007
```

Comment: It looks like it works just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b492/2/0

Comment: didn't know about sqlfiddle. Awesome site. Example I gave was subset of my table. Since, its working i'll try to add some more columns that are present in my table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes just listening to your own words in English translates into the easiest to read SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_id, a.code
   FROM my_table a
   WHERE a.user_id in 
       (SELECT b.user_id
       FROM my_table b
       WHERE b.ROLE_ID = 13)
    AND a.user_id in 
       (SELECT b.user_id
       FROM my_table b
       WHERE b.ROLE_ID = 15)
   AND a.user_id NOT IN 
       (SELECT b.user_id
       FROM my_table b
       WHERE b.ROLE_ID NOT IN (13,15))
```

Comment: I don't oracle, but I have a hard time believing that three subqueries is better than a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I will:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.code 
FROM my_table a
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.code 
HAVING sum(case when a.role_id in (13, 15) then 1 else 3 end) = 2
```

:)

Comment: This answer does not contain all of the required conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As proven by [EthanB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170150/logic-in-having-clause-to-get-multiple-values-of-a-group-by-result/12170361?noredirect=1#comment16289786_12170150), your query is working exactly as you desire.  There must be something in your project data that is not represented in your question's fabricated data.

I do endorse a pivot as you have executed in your question, but I would write it as a single `SUM` expression to reduce the number of iterations over the aggregate data.  I certainly do not endorse [multiple subqueries on each row of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12170361/2943403) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5970338/2943403), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424301/using-a-select-statement-within-a-where-clause), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141278/2943403)) ...regardless of whether the optimizer is converting the subqueries to multiple JOINs.

**Your pivot conditions:**

> ```
> having sum( case when a.role_id in (13,15) then 1 else 0 end) = 2
>    and sum( case when a.role_id in (11,14) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
> ```

**My recommendation:**

As the aggregate data is being iterated, you can keep a tally (+1) of qualifying rows and jump to a disqualifying outcome (+3) after each evaluation. This way, there is only one pass over the aggregate instead of two.

```
SELECT USER_ID, CODE
FROM my_table
WHERE ROLE_ID IN (13,15,11,14)
GROUP BY USER_ID, CODE
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ROLE_ID IN (13,15) THEN 1
                WHEN ROLE_ID IN (11,14) THEN 3 END) = 2
```

Another way of expressing what these HAVING clauses are doing is:

> Require that the first CASE is satisfied twice and that the second CASE is never satisfied.

[Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b492/22)

Alternatively, the above HAVING clause could be less elegantly written as:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE ROLE_ID
           WHEN 13 THEN 1
           WHEN 15 THEN 1
           WHEN 11 THEN 3
           WHEN 14 THEN 3
           END) = 2
```

**Disclaimer #1:** I don't swim in the `[oracle]` tag pool, I've not investigated how to execute this with `PIVOT`.

**Disclaimer #2:** My above advice assumes that `ROLE_ID`s are unique in the grouped `USER_ID`+`CODE` aggregate data.  Fringe cases: ([a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72cc5/1))

1. a given group contains `ROLE_ID = 13`, `ROLE_ID = 13`, and `ROLE_ID = 15` then of course the SUM will be at least 3 and the group will be disqualified.
2. a given group contains only `ROLE_ID = 15` and `ROLE_ID = 15` then of course the SUM will be 2 and the group will be unintentionally qualified.

To combat scenarios like these, make three separate MAX conditions.

```
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE_ID = 13 THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE_ID = 15 THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE_ID IN (11,14) THEN 1 END) IS NULL
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72cc5/13)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT user_id, code FROM my_table
WHERE role_id = 13
INTERSECT
SELECT user_id, code FROM my_table
WHERE role_id = 15
```

Comment: This answer does not contain all of the required conditions.