# mysql query - exclude an entry

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 tables, 1 table is **order** and another table is **order_items**. **Order_items** contains many records for a order_id from **order**. I would like to query table order so that, if the orders contain certain order_items (such as `product_item = 'nameProduct'`). it would exclude these orders out of the result. how should I do it?

My current queries are:

```
select * orders where order_id in (select order_id from order_items where product_item !='nameProduct');
```

this query not really working because the `select order_id from order_items where product_item !='nameProduct'` can still select entry that has same `order_id` but just has a different `product_item`

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    orders o
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   order_items oi
                     WHERE  product_item = 'nameProduct'
                            AND oi.order_id = o.order_id )
```

Comment: Performance-wise, does it matter if you do a `SELECT *` in the inner query versus something like `SELECT 'X'` or some other dummy value?

Comment: @NullUserException Probably not in MySQL. Sounds like the same arguments surrounding `COUNT(*)` vs `COUNT(1)`. FWIW, I've always used `SELECT 1` in `EXISTS` sub-queries

Comment: @Null - Shouldn't do. Definitely doesn't in SQL Server [as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1). The subquery might cause a problem [in MySQL though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190)