# MySQL - WHERE IN causes 100% cpu and no results

Tags: mysql, performance

This query takes a split second

```
select * from tbl1 limit 0,1
```

This query takes a second

```
SELECT Distinct(col2) FROM tbl2 WHERE col3 = 2
```

This query eats 100% cpu and takes 190 seconds duration (0s fetch) to return the result

```
select * from tbl1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT Distinct(col2) FROM tbl2 WHERE col3 = 2) limit 0,1
```

I am trying to run this query on the full data set (not just limiting it to one record)

What could be causing the performance problem, my table structures?

Comment: How many records are in tbl1?

Comment: Do you have an index on `tbl2.col3` ?

Comment: [The `IN` gets repeatedly re-evaluated for each row in the outer query.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190)

Comment: I thought it might get repeatedly get re-evaluated, is there a quicker way to achieve this without 'where in'? - I need to change the select to an update when I correct the performance issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subqueries in MySQL are notoriously slow.  You can speed this up with a join:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM
    tbl1 A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT col2
        FROM
            tbl2
        WHERE
            col3 = 2
    ) X ON X.col2 = A.ID
LIMIT 0, 1
```

To update `tbl1`:

```
UPDATE
    tbl1 A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT col2
        FROM
            tbl2
        WHERE
            col3 = 2
    ) X ON X.col2 = A.ID
SET
    A.SomeCol = 'value'
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, I have been using the select to try and figure out how long it takes just to select one row using my method, but really i need to do a mass update, is it possible to use the join method within an update?

Comment: With the assumption that `tbl1.ID` is unique or PK, then this is correct.

Comment: Chris, assuming you want to update a column on tbl1, sure.  I'll update my example.

Comment: I will try this and see if it works; UPDATE FROM tbl1 AS a
INNER JOIN (
select distinct(col2) from tbl2 where col3 = 2
) x on x.col2 = a.id
SET a.processed = 0

Comment: Thanks Sean, youve been a great help, I am ever so glad that there is a better way of doing this :)

Comment: The join method takes a split second and appears to have worked perfectly :D

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on `tbl2`, on `col3` or (even better) on `(col3,col2)`.

Then use this (no need for the `DISTINCT`here):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE col3 = 2) 
LIMIT  0,1
```

or even better, to avoid the `IN (SELECT ...)`, this version:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 t
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM tbl2 t2
        WHERE t2.col3 = 2 
          AND t2.col2 = t.ID
      ) 
LIMIT  0,1
```