# How different is WHERE id IN(4) versus WHERE id = 4?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would an IN condition be slower than “=” in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql)

Is there any performance difference between doing:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id IN (4)
```

Versus

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id = 4
```

Comment: did you try `explain select ...`?

Comment: That question is talking about using an IN statment in a subquery, e.g `SELECT FROM foo WHERE id IN (SELECT..)` whereas my question is the diff. between `SELECT WHERE id IN (val)` vs `SELECT WHERE id = val`. Hence its not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MySQL optimizer will convert the id IN(4) to id = 4, so no performance difference

Comment: does it say so anywhere in the manual?

Comment: Do you know or do you just think so?  Please dont answer questions with "I believe so"  please supply proof