# Mysql Execution of subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery

Say I've a query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_name 
FROM borrower 
WHERE customer_name in (SELECT customer_name FROM depositor)
```

We can consider above as two queries

**A**

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_name 
FROM borrower 
WHERE customer_name
```

**B**

```
SELECT customer_name 
FROM depositor
```

Which executes first? Is this rule the same for all sub queries?

What types of sub queries can we write? Give me some pointers to get started with a tutorial link.

Comment: Some pointers? What about the manual? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html

Comment: You could improve the IN with a EXISTS ... such as WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM depositor AS b WHERE b.customer_name = borrower.customer_name)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** as first answer was *wrong*. But explanaition was correct :|

**A** executes first. Applies "all" subqueries presented above as the subqueries are correlated.

```
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table     | type           | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | borrower  | index          | NULL          | customer_name | 52      | NULL |    6 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | depositor | index_subquery | customer_name | customer_name | 52      | func |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Btw. MySQL 6 will remove this problem and the selection type will become `PRIMARY` for both queries. See [1](http://www.bigdbahead.com/?p=187)

Comment: Not downvoting as MySQL isn't really my area but is this really true? So you're implying that in MySQL all sub queries get materialized into a temporary table first? MySQL can't for example do a merge join here?

Comment: MySQL is optimized for joins and won't optimize subqueries. Some subqueries can be written as destict selection to improve their speed. ´´SELECT col FROM t1 WHERE id_col IN (SELECT id_col2 FROM t2 WHERE condition);
That statement can be rewritten as follows:

SELECT DISTINCT col FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id_col = t2.id_col AND condition;´´

Comment: @MartinSmith: AFAIK the optimizer in MySQL is so limited that it won't rewrite such a query. MySQL has historically been very bad with sub-selects (I think it's actually stated in the manual somewhere)

Comment: What if `depositor` has 1 million rows and `borrower` two? Are you saying that it will still evaluate the query on  `depositor` first?

Comment: MySQL will do as explained above.

Comment: Martin: No, I think that the opposite is true. Subqueries in `WHERE` are not evaluated first but a lookup is done for every row in the external table. So, the efficiency would be worse when there are many rows in `borrower` and few in `depositor`. MariaDB latest versions have quite a lot optimizations strategies included: [MariaDB 5.3 and 5.5: Semi-join subquery optimizations](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/semi-join-subquery-optimizations/) MySQL 5.6 will have, too, some optimizer improvements.

Comment: @ypercube:Subqueries in WHERE are not evaluated first but a lookup is done for every row in the external table What do you mean by this ?Can you provide some more information.

Comment: @redsaw: See this answer at SO [Why would an IN condition be slower than “=” in sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190) and the link to MySQL buglist.

Comment: @ypercude:I could not under stand this ,can you explain this with example or in detail :Subqueries in WHERE are not evaluated first but a lookup is done for every row in the external table What do you mean by this ?