# Select DISTINCT and MAX in the same query

Tags: sql

I have a table with rows/data in the following structure

```
-----------
| SURVEY_ID |
------------
|  1       |
|  2       |
|  2       |
|  3       |
|  4       |
-----------
```

I want to get the distinct IDs and the maximum id in the same query. I tried

```
select distinct(survey_id) as survey_id , max(survey_id) as current 
from survey_main 
group by survey_id
```

This doesn't seem to return the correct result. What am I missing?

Edit: Required result

```
        ----------------------
        | Distinct|  Max     |
        ----------------------
        |  1       |  4      |
        |  2       |  4      |
        |  3       |  4      |
        |  4       |  4      |
        ----------------------
```

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql

Comment: Do you want the count of all survey_ids and the max (two columns, one row)?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka I just don't want to execute 2 separate queries for a minor thing. The max value repeating in each row is fine with me.

Comment: @Vaishak Suresh - got it, gave u a simple answer

Comment: Can you please show us your desired result?

Comment: See my proposal below, that does exactly what you want. Don't worry about the sub-select - usually the database caches a lot so it won't be too slow ;-)

Comment: In this case, Distinct and Group By do the same same thing. There is no need to use both.

Comment: @Andre http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql

Comment: @Itay Moav -Malimovka: that is really an interesting point though it's not applicable to the proposal I made; Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think *Itay Moav-Malimovka*'s solution is just perfect, however if you really want to have two columns you could use ....

```
select distinct(survey_id) as identifier, 
       (select max(survey_id) from survey) as "current" 
  from survey_main;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

If you are after the count of all survey_ids and the max in one query, try this:

```
select count(distinct survey_id) as number_of_survey_ids 
     , max(survey_id) as current 
from survey_main
```

And if you want to add the max value to every row **and** your database supports window functions, try this:

```
select survey_id 
     , max(survey_id) over () as current 
from survey_main
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM T
ORDER BY SURVEY_ID DESC
```

The first result is the MAX, the entire Dataset is the distinct

Comment: Isn't really what I wanted. I wanted the query to return the max, I can anyway parse the resultset manually.