# SQL select addresses from a state in single query from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I don't know if the title makes any sense, but here is the situation: See 2 tables below

**People:** (BTW, if it helps to know, this table will never have >1000 rows)

```
+----+---------+-------------------+---------+
| id |  name   |      address      | city_id |
+----+---------+-------------------+---------+
|  1 | person1 | some address      |     123 |
|  2 | person2 | another address   |     542 |
|  3 | person3 | different address |     623 |
+----+---------+-------------------+---------+
```

**Cities:** (this one may contain all cities with states(and addl. column for country) around the globe)

```
+-----+-------+--------+
| id  | city  | state  |
+-----+-------+--------+
| 123 | city1 | state1 |
| 542 | city2 | state1 |
| 623 | city3 | state2 |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

To start, I know only `people.id`. Using this I need to find all people that belong to same `state` (**not same `city`**). For example, if I have `people.id=1`, I need to get all people from the **state** that person1 (people.id = 1) belongs to:

**Output:**

```
+----+---------+-----------------+---------+
| id |  name   |     address     | city_id |
+----+---------+-----------------+---------+
|  1 | person1 | some address    |     123 |     /*Both the people are from state1*/
|  2 | person2 | another address |     542 |
+----+---------+-----------------+---------+
```

I'm able to achieve this in two queries: A variable `$state` storing output of

`SELECT c.state from people p INNER JOIN cities c ON p.city_id=c.id where p.id=<my input>;`

and then another query

`SELECT a.* FROM`people`a INNER JOIN`cities`b ON a.city_id=b.id WHERE b.state=$state`

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this with a single JOIN? I tried combining the two queries to `SELECT` with JOIN within a JOIN(in subquery) which doesn't feel right somehow.

**P.S: *I'm not looking for recommendations on normalization or other changes to schema. All that is already in consideration for another development branch for later upgrade.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below query-

```
SELECT p2.*
FROM people p 
JOIN cities c ON p.city_id=c.id 
JOIN cities c2 ON c.state=c2.state  
JOIN people p2 ON p2.city_id=c2.id 
WHERE p.id=<my input>;
```

Note: For performance id and city_id in people table and id and state in cities table should be indexed.

Also for more optimization you should use state_id instead of state for join and for this you have to create state_id field in your table.

Comment: I think you misread my question. i need people that live in same state as `<my input>`... this will give me all people from same city. BTW, even the query in your answer can be performed with just a single join. 2nd join is not essential.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr  `2nd join is not essential` - I think you've misread the answer. This _doesn't_ do what you want but it's not helpful to ask a question and comment on each answer "I've already tried/thought of that" - it indicates your question can be clearer that you're getting answers you've already tried or miss the point.

Comment: @AD7six: thanks for pointing out. Highlighted the specific requirement in question.

Comment: the edit doesn't really help - **putting everything in bold makes it harder to read** what would help is being more concise and simply showing what you've already tried (not describing, *showing*, and saying why what you've tried didn't work/isn't what you want). No need to reply to me individually, the advice is there for the taking, or not =).

Comment: The updated query does work. I already have the indexes you suggested. About changing the schema, I can't afford it as it is but I will consider that for another branch I'm working on where the major focus is on improvement of performance. Thanks. BTW, I don't know which approach is more efficient - your solution or my existing approach of doing two separate queries. In a quick test, both did almost equally. I don't have huge dataset in reality to test this. I'll accept this solution if I don't get a better one by evening. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You might try this.

```
select * from people
where city_id in(
    select city from cities c
    inner join(
        select c.state from people p
        left join cities c on c.city = p.city_id
        where p.id = '1'
    ) s on s.state = c.state
)
```

Comment: Well, this looks like an overkill... pretty much similar to what I wanted to avoid... already mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr And you also mention this `this table will never have >1000 rows`

Comment: But the `cities` table may have 100,000 rows or even more... BTW I already know of this solution as noted in question, I'm looking for an optimized query which doesn't have to do a Join within a JOIN

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM people p1 
WHERE p1.city_id in (
    SELECT c1.id 
    FROM cities c1 
    WHERE c1.state IN (
        SELECT c2.state 
        FROM people p2,
             cities c2 
        WHERE c2.id = p2.city_id 
          AND p2.id = 1
        )
    );
```

Instead of `p2.id = 1` in the query, give the id of person from people table to whom you want to get the data.

Comment: i thought using `in()` is not a very good idea for performance. Surprisingly, `Explain` shows same plan for [Zafar Malik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33009238/1369473) which makes me believe that the query is re-written by optimizer to follow similar execution plan. Further research lead me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql) which clarifies a lot of things

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.* from 
people as a
inner join (
select cityid from people where personid = <my input>
) as b on b.cityid = a.cityid
```

-- or --

```
WITH CTE as
(
    select cityid from people where personid = <my input>
)

select a.* from people as a
inner join CTE as b on b.cityid = a.cityid;
```

Comment: Doesn't this just fetch the people from same city, if at all? I need people within same state as input person `id`